# Is there a word or phrase for the subversion of a pleasant thing becoming a negative thing?

Tags: single-word-requests, psychology, emotions

When something associated with positive emotions becomes associated with its opposite negative emotions, it often appears to embody these emotions more strongly than something that didn't have the original positive emotion. An example of this subversion is the fear of clowns, although there are numerous examples, some used intentionally in works of art. What is the name for this effect?

Comment: fear of [thing] is called a phobia of that thing: phobia of clowns. However, if a person ha a phobia of clowns, who is to say if they ever had "positive emotions" about them.

Comment: Welcome! Although this is pretty well explained, requests for words or phrases have a requirement for a sample sentence showing how the word would be used. Perhaps something like: "I used to love that song, but it was playing on my headphones when I was mugged, and now it triggers a traumatic response, a textbook case of ___."

Comment: Though that example would probably be a specialized psychological term, perhaps better asked on the psychology stack exchange. Maybe you're asking for something broader and societal, like "Images of angels, usually associated with heavenly peace, were ____ed in the popular consciousness by the TV show *Dr. Who* and its terrifyingly malignant 'Weeping Angels.'" So that's why including a sample sentence is recommended; it helps clarify your context and use.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is that this is a form of **inversion**

> [American Psychological Association](https://dictionary.apa.org/inversion)
>
> inversion
> n. in Piagetian theory, see negation.
>
> negation
> n. in Piagetian theory, a mental process—a form of reversibility—in which one realizes that any operation can always be negated or inverted. Also called inversion.

This derives from and is consistent with a more general definition:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inversion)
>
> Inversion
> a situation in which something is changed so that it is the opposite of what it was before, or in which something is turned upside down

Hence, we may find references to processes such as emotional inversion, which encourages more positive behaviour, or institutional inversion, which inadvertently reinforces negative behaviour.

I have not been able to find a conventional form that fits your specification of a negative change of feeling. Perhaps it is a **phobic inversion**

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/phobic)
>
> Phobic
> having a strong dislike or hatred of something, especially in a way that is extreme or not reasonable: